# Extended class pulling through NULL - OOP

Tags: php, class, oop, extends

I have the following class for all my user methods:

```
class User {
  protected $_db,
            $_data;

  public function __construct($user = null, $findby = 'id') {
    $this->_db = DB::getInstance();

    if (!$user) {
      ........
    } else {
      ........
    }
  }

 .......

  public function login($username = null, $password = null) {
    $user = $this->find($username, 'username');
    if ($user) {
      $lockdown = new Lockdown; 
    }
  }

  public function find($param = null, $method = null) {
    if ($param && $method) {
      $data = $this->_db->query("SELECT * FROM users ...");
      if ($data->count()) {
        $this->_data = $data->result();
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  public function data() {
    return $this->_data;
  } 
}
```

The above is a completely stripped down version of my user class. I also have another class (lockdown) which extends user:

```
class Lockdown extends User {
  public $getAttempts;

  public function __construct() {
    var_dump($this->data());
    die();
  }
}
```

However when i call the lockdown class inside of the login class, even though the data object should contain all the user information, the var_dump() is simply returning NULL.

From my calculations when the login class is called, the **find method** should set $_data = USER INFO, which should therefore allow the new Lockdown method invoked just after the ($this->find()) to be able to access the same data method.

I am still learning OOP Programming so don't know if there is something i am missing, but i can't seem to understand the reason as to why the Lockdown class returns NULL on the data method when it should inherit it.

Comment: Hi @mic, thanks for your response. I've added the User::__construct() class to the original question, and don't see how calling it would help get the _data variable filled. May i ask why the _data variable is not being populated, as the code seems to suggest that the data method should be executed before calling Lockdown?

Comment: In your Lockdown's __construct() you need to add parent::__construct() before you call var_dump

Comment: parent::__construct() worked as long as i provided the username into the __construct() method. All working now thanks. However one more quick thing, why is it parent::__construct() when neither on my methods are static?

Comment: @MatthewM you need to take note of tereško answer.

Comment: Passing in `$this` as a constructor parameter? Are you insane or just delusional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not put any computation logic inside a constructor. It makes it hard to test. You also cannot return from a constructor.

You structure is a complete disaster. Both because of your abuse of the inheritance and of global state.

It makes no sense for a class to create a new instance of its own child class for retrieving data. This is probably a result of you attempting to for a `User` class to combine two different responsibilities: persistence and business logic. This constitutes a violation of [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), which then manifest in a form of a convoluted call graph.

Also the whole `class Lockdown extends User` construct makes no sense. The `extends` keyword in OOP can be translates as "is special case of" (as per [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)). The class for tracing user's login attempts is not a specialized case of "user".

You should have at least 3 separate classes for this: one for handling the "user's behavior" and other for saving/restoring "user's state" (the approach is called "[data mapper](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html)"). The third one would be for managing the the failed attempts.

I would also highly recommend watching [**this lecture**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KHBrDWIKW8Q).

As for global state, instead of using a singleton anti-pattern, you should have passed the database connection as a constructor's dependency to the class, which need to interact with persistence.

As for the code, at a high level, it should probably looks something like this:

```
$user = new User;
$mapper = new UserMapper($db);

$user->setName($username)
if ($mapper->fetch($user)) {
   if ($user->matchPassword($password)) {
       // you have logged in
       // add some flag in session about it
       header('Location: /greetings');
       exit;
   }
   // check the failed attempts
} else {
  // no matching username 
}
```